# Contacts without Opportunities

Tags: opportunitycontactrole

1) I need to see if a contact has an opportunity. 
2) If not, I will create a new opportunity.
3) I'd like to do this with Process Builder.

Part 1 is my challenge. How do I test to see if a contact has an associated Opportunity with Process builder? FYI. we've implemented Contact roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute queries with Process Builder. You will have to break out to either Apex Code or a Flow. If you want to stick with with configuration-only, then the Flow would be the way to go about it. You'd have an input variable for the Contact ID, then a Fast Lookup for Contact Roles. If there are none, then you know there's no opportunity, and you can create one from there.